# Acces selected packages using Package Manager

Tags: android, android-package-managers

How to access only those packages in Android(using Package Manager) which are allowed to be accessed by the user and display it in a listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the package manager with [getInstalledPackages()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)) or [getInstalledApplications()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int)):

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> list = pm.getInstalledPackages(0)
```